# How to increase sensitivity of sound sensor?

Tags: operational-amplifier, esp32, microphone, sound

I'm using a [sound sensor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07R452F6J), hooked up to an [ESP32](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09QW6Y7KY), to determine whether a medium-sized pump is running or not.

While this works well when the pump is running loudly, it works less well when the pump is running quietly. For this reason, I would really like to boost the analog signal I'm getting out of the sound sensor, to detect the more faint sounds coming from the pump.

It seems like I might be able to use an op-amp of some sort. Is that correct? If so, what op-amp circuit could I use? The ESP32 I'm using has a 5 V power source (not sure if I need something of a higher voltage as well).

Full disclosure, I'm a web-developer who dabbles with ESP32s and Raspberry Pis. Not an EE in the slightest.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to electronics SE. Are you using the digital or analog output of the sound module? Where is the module located in regards to the motor (next to it, near it, etc).

Comment: Can you make a picture of the pump? The esp had an hall sensor , maybe you can do something with that. Also other possibilities

Comment: Search CT sensor and arduino. Maybe a nice alternative

Comment: @AnasMalas I'm using the analog output of the sound module. The sensor is attached directly to the pump.

Comment: @RemyHx Thanks, I appreciate the recommendation. With a CT sensor, wouldn't I need to split the pump's power cable into its different wires? My understanding of CT sensors, is that they can only go over one lead, otherwise the current reading gets cancelled out.

Comment: Would a sensor attached to the pump's fan (if it has one) work? Also, your mic may just have bad response for low frequencies. Perhaps try a [mems microphone module](https://www.amazon.com/Adafruit-I2S-MEMS-Microphone-Breakout/dp/B06XNL2GBW/ref=mp_s_a_1_4?crid=HG5LGYDYIBAI&keywords=mems+microphone+module&qid=1668192271&sprefix=mems+microphone+module%2Caps%2C231&sr=8-4)

Comment: Also make sure your microphone is mounted rigidly to the pump, dont use something like tape or a ziptie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an op-amp could be used to boost the analog audio output of the sensor, but that's the hard way to address your problem. Using the analog input of the ESP to detect sound requires code that wastes CPU cycles too.

Try using the digital output of the sensor instead, feeding a digital input of the ESP.  The sensor appears to have an adjustable threshold  set by a trim-pot -- it's the blue square with the screw head on top, possibly offering 10 turns of adjustment. An LED on the sensor should indicate when it triggers from sound in this mode.

With higher sensitivity, you may detect the pump, but experience false triggering from ambient noise. To address this, move the sensor closer to the pump. Or try making a little megaphone (rolled up from paper) with its small end over the microphone housing and the large end pointed toward the pump.

I should mention that there are also electrical ways to detect when a pump is running, if the acoustic approach proves unreliable.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! Not to get too much into the weeds, but the sensor needs to be scalable to other pumps as well, and quickly deployable, meaning a static threshold via the trim-pot won't work. The ESP32 pushes data to a cloud-based server, which is processing the audio-values, and where I can set the threshold for different pumps. I've also created a mount for the sensor, which helps transmit the sound from the pump more directly. At this point, the only optimization I can do would be to amplify the signal. For this application, I also can't use electrical. Great idea though!

Comment: I found a schematic of the sensor, which shows it has only a dual comparator (LM393) to provide the digital output. I'm surprised to see no amplification at all between the mic and the analog output. So you could benefit from an op-amp. Look at example schematics to see how to generate a Vcc/2 voltage so the signal can swing positive and negative. Also look at MAX4465 - 4468 series, which are dedicated microphone preamplifiers.

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate the help. I'll check out some schematics, and look into the MAX4465 - 4468 series.